# JQuery external link confirm mobile compatibility

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios5

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('a.external').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var speedBump = confirm("You are now leaving this website. Do you want to continue?");
            if (speedBump) {
                document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
            };
    });
});
```

For some reason this code does not work correctly on both android and iOS. Any ideas why?  Instead of redirecting the intended URL, it redirects to the About Us page of the same site, which makes no sense.

UPDATE: I substituted `$(this).attr('href')` for `http://www.google.com` and the script worked perfectly,

Is there any reason that this.attr wouldn't work on mobile?

Comment: whether the confirm message is appearing?

Comment: Everything works fine on a desktop, on a mobile the confirm message appears but the redirect doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was for a mobile page, the funky behavior was solved by updating my mobile jQuery from versions 1.1.0 to 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.target` instead of `this`. It's set by the event object for cross-browser use.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/